# How to make company-lsp case sensitive?

Tags: company-mode, lsp-mode

Currently if I try to complete a work, the case of the prefix is ignored with company-lsp.

From looking into the code, `company-lsp` is hard-coded to use `ignore-case`.

As at the time of writing `company--begin-new` calls: `(company-call-backend 'ignore-case))`

Is there a way to make company-lsp case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

`company-lsp` is deprecated use `company-capf` (just delete `company-lsp` and `lsp-mode` will pick it). company-capf is case-sensitive by default.